# Consecutive keyup events not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am creating a program that needs to handle three consecutive key presses of the enter button. My first eventListener works as planned. However, when the user input is incorrect, and the program moves onto the second eventListener, the program always runs the else statement regardless of whether the user input was correct or not. I tried including a variable, again, to capture user input at the second eventListener (thinking it was still reading the first user input) but the result was no different.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Enter Missing Text</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="quote"></p>
  <p id="correctResponse"></p>
  <p id="incorrectResponse"></p>
  <script>
    let quote = ['For score and', '7', 'years ago.'];
    let helper = '  ';
    for (i = 0; i < quote.length; i++) {
      if (i === 1) {
        quote[1] = "<input type='text' id='txtBox'><br>";
      }
      helper += quote[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = helper;
    document.getElementById('txtBox').focus();

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var userInput = document.createElement('foo');
        userInput.textContent = txtBox.value;
        if (userInput.textContent == '7' || userInput.textContent == 'seven') {
          document.getElementById('correctResponse').innerHTML = 'awesome.';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('incorrectResponse').innerHTML = "sorry. try again";
          document.getElementById('txtBox').value = " ";
          document.getElementById('txtBox').focus();
        }

        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            var userInput = document.createElement('foo');
            userInput.textContent = txtBox.value;
            if (userInput.textContent == '7' || userInput.textContent == 'seven') {
              document.getElementById('correctResponse').innerHTML = 'awesome.';
            } else {
              document.getElementById('incorrectResponse').innerHTML = "give it one more try";
              document.getElementById('txtBox').value = " ";
              document.getElementById('txtBox').focus();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing for me - 3 consecutive keyups? Why 3? Or are you just wanting the user to enter '7' and press enter and show an error if the input contains a value other than 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove previous listener and add the next one in case the answer is wrong:

(any input value other than `7` will circle through handlers)

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');

function isEnter(event) {
  return event.keyCode === 13
}

function f1(event) {
  if (isEnter(event)) {
    if (event.target.value !== '7') {
      result.innerText = 'wrong 1';
      event.target.addEventListener('keyup', f2);
      event.target.removeEventListener('keyup', f1);
    } else {
      result.innerText = 'right 1';
    }
  }
}

function f2(event) {
  if (isEnter(event)) {
    if (event.target.value !== '7') {
      result.innerText = 'wrong 2';
      event.target.addEventListener('keyup', f3);
      event.target.removeEventListener('keyup', f2);
    } else {
      result.innerText = 'right 2';
    }
  }
}

function f3(event) {
  if (isEnter(event)) {
    if (event.target.value !== '7') {
      result.innerText = 'wrong 3';
      event.target.addEventListener('keyup', f1);
      event.target.removeEventListener('keyup', f3);
    } else {
      result.innerText = 'right 3';
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('arrr').addEventListener('keyup', f1);
```

```html
<input type="text" id='arrr'>
<p id='result'></p>
```